# Natural Logarithm Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

There is a definition in my text that I don't really get the significance of. Could someone tell me what is the purpose of it?

Definition: The natural Logarithm function is the function for $x>0$ defined by $$\ln x=\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt.$$

Why is it $t$ (is it cause $x$ is already being used in the bounds)? What do those bounds have to do with $\ln$? From problems regarding this I see that I always have to make the functions bound start at 1 and end with $x$, why is that?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can you provide examples of "problems regarding this" that you mention in your third question below the integral?  It's hard to answer without knowing more specifics.

Comment: note that for $0 \lt x \lt 1$ you should read  $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt$ as $\displaystyle - \int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{t} dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably:

$\displaystyle \ln x := \int_1^x \frac1t \ \mathrm dt$

where $:=$ means "is defined as".

---

From the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus):

$\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln x = \frac 1x$

The lower bound is $1$ to make $\ln1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By integrating, then evaluating at limits of integral and simplifying:

$$\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt=(\ln t)_1^x$$
$$=\ln x - \ln 1 = \ln x$$

Answer (score 0):

The following is the graph of $y=\frac{1}{x}$ showing the region bounded between the graph and the $x$-axis and bounded between vertical lines $x=1$ and $x=c$.

The area of the region is

$$\int_1^c\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\ln(c)\tag{1}$$

If one prefers to define the natural logarithm function in terms of $x$ rather than in terms of $c$, then one must use some other symbol than $x$ for the horizontal axis. Any other letter will be suitable, such as, for example, the letter $t$.

Then we write

$$\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}\,dt=\ln(x)\tag{2}$$

The issue is not to use one symbol $x$ to represent two different things. In equation $(1)$, $c$ is the constant and $x$ is the horizontal coordinate axis. In equation $(2)$, $x$ is the constant and $t$ is the horizontal coordinate axis.

[image: graph showing def of ln(x)]